# Custom link content type should open a modal window to for adding a new link

Tags: content-type

My custom link content type is not showing as Modal window, but Add a New Link window is showing in the same Window, I want it to display in Modal window

Comment: Check in the list settings. There should be an option to choose modal windows vs regular window.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assunming you are working with SharePoint 2010, since you expect dialogs. Go to the List (or Library) Settings / Advanced Settings / Dialogs (all the way at the bottom), and make sure that the radio button is set to "Yes".

Comment: I have the same issue, your answer does not fix the problem